# RichTextbox coloring behaviour

Tags: c#, regex, windows, richtextbox

I am currently trying to develop an software whose behaviour is similar to Notepad++s. Regarding the 'coloring' part, I use regex and an external file containing the regex & color of each word.

The file looks following:

```
<script&blue
/>&blue
\".*?\"&red
```

The software then reads the file and converts it into an string array 'string[]' by splitting it at each newline character. This array is called '**Correctors**'. I then use following method to find & set the color of each word matching regex pattern:

```
foreach (string corrector in Correctors) {
    string[] spTxt = corrector.Split('&');

    Match matches = Regex.Match(rtb_Main.Text, spTxt[0]);
    Color color = Color.FromName(spTxt[1]);

    while (matches.Success)
    {
        rtb_Main.SelectionStart = matches.Index;
        rtb_Main.SelectionLength = matches.Length;

        rtb_Main.SelectionColor = color;
        matches = matches.NextMatch();
    }
}
```

This is where the issue occurs. The method is working as supposed for the last string in the array 'Correctors'. However; it seems that the other objects in the array is being either overwritten or ignored as the words matching their patterns is not being colored.

What is wrong?

Thanks in advance, 

  - Rasmus.

Comment: Are you getting an exception? A weird result? If so, it would help if you posted them.

Answer (score 2):

Didn't you get any error while compiling this. I mean to say how did you get:

```
 while (matches.Success)
```

It should have been like this..

```
            // Use foreach loop.
            foreach (Match match in matches)
            {
                if(match.Success)
                {
                    //Change color here...
                }
            }
```