# Color characters based on regular expression

Tags: c#, regex, windows, winforms, richtextbox

I am a .Net beginner. I want to color some characters inside a rich text box based on the selected regular expression. How to do this?

Like:

```
if (Regex.IsMatch(richTextBox, @"^[a-m]{1}$"))
{
   ??? //coloring that particular character of richTextBox
}
```

What should I write in it? can the same done using label?

Comment: possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2527700/change-color-of-text-within-a-winforms-richtextbox

Comment: check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12437880/richtextbox-coloring-behaviour

Comment: @KPL can this be done using labels. because i used label in my project not richtextbox( my friend suggested to use richtextbox instead).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try using `Paragraph`s with `Run`s

```
Paragraph para = new Paragraph {
    Foreground = Brushes.Red,
};
para.Inlines.Add(new Bold(new Run(matchingString)));
para.Inlines.Add(new Run(regularText));
myRichTextBox.Document.Blocks.Add(para);
```

etc

Answer (score 2):

If you want to iterate through all matches. Not sure whether Regex.Matches ever returns null, thus I checked the result.

```
 MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(rtb.Text, @"^[a-m]{1}$");
 if (matches != null && matches.Count > 0)
 {
     foreach (Match m in matches)
     {
         rtb.Select(m.Index, m.Length);
         rtb.SelectionColor = Color.Blue;
     }
 }
```